# Why am I not getting correct value when attempting to find the average value of n elements?

Tags: c++

I'm going through an O'reilly programming book, and one of the questions is to "write a program to average n elements".

This is the code that I have:

```
#include <iostream>

int n; //number of numbers
int number; //the numbers to be averaged
float avg; //the average of the elements
int counter; //iterator

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of elements you want averaged: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    avg = 0;

    counter = 0;
    while (counter < n)
    {
        std::cout << "enter number: ";
        std:: cin >> number;

        number += number;

        ++counter;

    }

    avg = number/n;

    std::cout << "Average of your " << n << " elements is: " << avg;

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, when I try to use 3 values of 3, i get a average of 2. I'm certain there's a problem with my declaration of "number" because it doesn't take the value of each number I enter and add it with each other. Could someone help me fix my mistake. I want my code to work for the general case; not just 3 elements. Thanks.

Comment: Every time you say `cin >> number;`, it overwrites the previous value. `number += number;` multiplies it by two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems.

1)

```
    std:: cin >> number;

    number += number;
```

I assume that `number` is meant to be the sum of all numbers, but here you are also using it to store a single number, and when you assign a value to a variable it overrides what was already there. You must use two different variable names, such as

```
    std:: cin >> number;

    sum += number;
```

2)

`number/n;` is integer division since `number` is integer and `n` is integer. Integer division rounds down. Having the result of the expression assigned to a float is not enough - it is too late, the expression was already computed as integer division.

You want float division, so do `sum/(double)n` for example.

Comment: Thanks man, this fixed the problem. But, I believe you mean "sum/(double)n". Regardless, thanks.

Comment: @MauriceAbney Yes, that is true, after fixing 1) you would fix 2) like that.

Answer (score 1):

You read the number `3`. The you say `number += number`, which makes it `6`, and increment counter to `1`. Then you read number again, it becomes `3`, add it again, again `6`, increment, counter. The third time, the same happens.

So you get `6/2` which is 3.

Answer (score 0):

You read the input into `number`, but you aren't actually keeping a total of all the numbers entered which is what you really need for this problem.